# Update Multiple records in sql - syntax

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to update multiple records.

**tbl_test** - existing table

```
EmployeeName Effort  Date
aaa            8     2014-10-21
bbb            9     2014-10-21
ccc            7     2014-10-21
```

**@dtCSV**  - table type as parameter

```
EmployeeName Effort
aaa           10    
ccc           10
```

**Expected output:**

```
EmployeeName Effort  Date
aaa           10     2014-10-21
bbb            9     2014-10-21
ccc           10     2014-10-21
```

This code gives an error - *Incorrect syntax near 't'*. What is the correct syntax to do this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SaveEffort
( 
    @TimesheetDate datetime, //(2014-10-21)
    @dtCSV AS dbo.SaveEffort_TableType readonly
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_test t
        SET t.Effort = d.Effort
    FROM @dtCSV d
    WHERE t.EmployeeName = d.EmployeeName
          AND t.[Date] = @TimesheetDate 
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 UPDATE t
 SET t.Effort = d.Effort
 FROM tbl_test t JOIN @dtCSV d
 ON t.EmployeeName = d.EmployeeName
 WHERE t.[Date] = @TimesheetDate
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. If I want to write 'update tbl_test' instead for readability, how should the rest of the code be.

Comment: You're welcome. We can only put the alias of the table be updated right after the UPDATE keyword. Without the that alias, you are to use the real table name throughout the the SQL statement.